# Header and section merging/overlaying each other

Tags: html, css

I'm a total beginner, so forgive me if this is a dumb question. I want to have a section separated from the header, but two situations are happening:

(1) When I put a `<section>` below the `</header>`, they overlap each other, like this:
[Section overlapping header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uJ5d.jpg) (The section is the "Compassion is our compass").

(2) However, when I put the `<section>`  *inside* of the `<header>` in the html, it looks normal: [Section inside of the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVukh.jpg).

The thing is that I don't want the section to be inside the header, because after all, it's not part of the header, it's in the showcase area, so I want it to be a different thing. But I also want it to display the same way it does when I put it inside the header.

I've deleted some things from the code (icons, logo and menu) to make it less messy and better for you guys.

**Code of the (1) situation (Overlapping):**

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="info">
                <!-- Icons and emails -->
            </div>

            <div id="branding">
                <!-- Logo -->
            </div>

             <nav>
                <ul>
                    <!-- Navbar Menu is here -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Compassion is our Compass</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.6em;
}

.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:auto;
    width:80%;
}

/*HEADER*/
header{
    background:#6fc4e2;
    max-height:30px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

 #branding{
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
    max-height:300px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border-bottom:#6fc4e2 solid 2px;
}

 header nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 15px 0 15px;
}
```

**Code of the (2) situation (Looks normal, but section is inside the header (don't want that)):**

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="info">
                <!-- Icons and emails -->
            </div>

            <div id="branding">
                <!-- Logo -->
            </div>

             <nav>
                <ul>
                    <!-- Navbar Menu is here -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <section id="showcase">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Compassion is our Compass</h1>
          </div>
        </section>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS is the same.

PS: the same thing was happening to the nav, but I decided to just leave it inside the header to save me the trouble.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, I hope you guys understand

And here's the full code if anyone wants to test it: https://justpaste.it/5sr2a

Comment: do you have any css for your `#showcase`?

Comment: No CSS for the showcase

Comment: you have two divs with the same id container change the second

Answer (score 0):

you are giving your `<header>` the `max-height: 30px;` it seems you did that for the background, but since your content is "higher" than 30px it overflows your `<header>` but the selection starts after those 30px. thats why it is overlapped.
 remove the `max-height` of your header and add the `background-color` only to the element you want to have it on. Not the parent element.

Comment: That was it! I put the height and background-color on the 'info' div and it's working correctly now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code for clarity. If you run this in your browser, I believe it gives you what you want. For this example, the CSS is in the HTML page; you would normally separate that out to your CSS file. I hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            line-height: 1.6em;
        }

        #info {
            max-height: 30px;
            background: #6fc4e2;
        }

        #branding {
            padding-top: 20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            max-height: 300px;
            width: 80%;
            border-bottom: #6fc4e2 solid 2px;
        }

        #info,
        #showcase,
        nav {
            padding-left: 10%;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="info">
            Icons and emails (info)
        </div>

        <div id="branding">
            Logo (branding)
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                Navbar Menu is here
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="showcase">
        <h1>Compassion is our Compass</h1>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may work with CSS `position` property. Setting both, `header` and `section` their positions to `absolute` can help reach what you intend to do – if you keep `header` and `section` separated in `HTML` (it’s not a good practice to put `section` inside `header` element). The solution for you could be this approach:

```
header{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* the rest of your style */
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 /* the rest of your style */
}
```

And, you need to remove `padding-right` property within `header` element to avoid horizontal scrolling.